# Trying to hook up dimmer/fan switch but have an extra wire?

Tags: electrical, switch, light, fans

I am trying to replace a switch that had a 4 position light knob and a 4 position fan knob.  The old one had three wires coming out of it and the new one has 4.  Below is a picture of my wall and the new switch:
[image]

And here are the instructions:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way that I can properly wire this switch or do I need to return it and buy a different type?  If I need to get a different one, what should I look for?

Comment: Do you know which of the load wires goes to the light and which goes to the fan?

Comment: Looking at the switch: black gets incoming power. Red to fan. Yellow to light. Green where it goes (if you don't know where that is, hire this job out).

Comment: What extra wire? That bare one? .... yeah, time to hire someone.

Comment: @Mazura - the bare wire was in the box but no hooked to anything.  I've heard that bare copper wires are grounds so that's what I assume it is but I'm not sure why they would have two different types of grounds in there.  It's possible the bare wire isn't hooked to anything.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - yeah I know which wire is for fan and which is for light.  Just sort of thrown for a loop that there aren't three black wires to hook to as shown in the diagram.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - would terrible things happen if I just capped of the black wire and then hooked up the red/yellow/green like they had been with the previous switch?

Comment: In the diagram, one of the wires coming from the wall is red.  You can't see it because it's printed in black & white!  No seriously, they can't show you because they don't know *in your particular installation* whether the fan is red or the fan is black.

Comment: @Harper - hrrm, what would that mean for my installation?  I know where all the wires coming from the wall should go - I just don't know what to do with the black wire coming from the switch.

Comment: Yeah my "black and white" quip wasn't so far off the mark. Colors mean less than you would hope for in mains wiring. Any hot is allowed to be any color but green (whaaa? Hots can be white!? Yeah...) You have to look at functional roles and/or measure or test.  Fortunately this one is easy, we know the /3 goes to the fan/light since separate control requires 3 wires.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere in the world, green, green/yellow or bare colors are reserved for ground.  The only exceptions are the former Soviet Bloc, and they now have harmonized to this rule too.  *So that is as simple as that.*  Grounds are never used to flow current normally, and only come up in fault conditions when it is time to save your bacon.  So from a logical, "how does this circuit *work* perspective, they are disregarded.  I never show them in diagrams, but they are always there.

Your old controller controlled the fan and light separately, so it *plainly* had 3 wires because that is the bare minimum needed to do that.  Your new one has 3 wires (from a functional perspective). Therefore, this is easy.  Go to it!

If you are unclear which cable is supply, most likely if one cable is 2-wire (black/white) and the other cable is  3-wire (red too) then the 3-wire must necessarily be the one going to the fan, and the 2-wire goes to supply.

Comment: Wait!  The new one has 4 wires.... right?  Three hot and one that hooks to the ground.  The previous had 3 wires - two hot and a ground.  If you are saying one fewer because you don't count grounds then there is still a one wire difference between the switches.  That's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: That is impossible unless the old fan controller had some proprietary control scheme that controlled both fan and light on one wire, which would then indicate a control module up in the fan *that is a matched set to the old switch*. We need to know a lot more about the old controller.  Can you get a model number?

Comment: I actually have the old controller hooked back up since I was having trouble with the new one.  I don't have a model number, but could snap a picture if it would help?  The old one has three wires coming out of it: black, yellow and green.  The black/yellow are hooked to the black wires in the wall, the green hooked to the ground and the bare wire from the wall is not attached to anything.  Let me know if I should post a picture of it

Comment: wait, what does the red wire do with the old controller?  Does it change the fan speed and dim the lights at the same time or are they separately controlled?

Comment: Well there's no red wire on the old controller.  That's where the confusion comes in - there are 4 wires on the new controller and 3 on the old one.  On the old one the fan and the light are controlled separately.  The yellow wire controls the light and the black controls the fan.

Comment: No, that's not what is happening, because you forgot a necessary third (non-ground) wire - supply.   The only way that is physically possible, is it must be an electronic device communicating with a controller in the ceiling using a proprietary protocol unique to that brand/model of hardware.  This type of kit is specifically made to allow separate fan/light control over only 2 wires.  They are a matched set, and must be replaced/substituted as a matched set.  Hence my interest in a model number.  Can you get photos of what's going on up in the fan box?

Comment: @Brh -- is it possible that your old control didn't have a ground wire/screw?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I'm not sure how the internals of the switch were wired, but one of the wires that was coming out of the switch was connected to the ground wire coming from the wall and everything seemed to work fine.